# Established homebrew specifics: is asking on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, homebrew

Is it on topic to ask about the specifics of established homebrew content (such as the house rules used by Matt Mercer on Critical Role) or where such things can be found?

Comment: Semi-related: [Where do I find “Where do I find Obscure-RPG-Document”?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5944/where-do-i-find-where-do-i-find-obscure-rpg-document)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you want here? Do you have a specific example or examples of questions you might want to ask along these lines that you can give us?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "established"? Note that technically per our tagging definitions if "established" here means "published" then it likely is [not considered homebrew](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7758/is-the-dmsguild-considered-homebrew-and-if-so-should-we-always-use-the-homebrew?s=1|57.8468), but published 3rd party content.

Comment: I mentioned Matt Mercer’s stuff because I’m thinking of asking about that. I’d like to find a complete list of his “official” house rules that he applies to Critical Role, as I’ve heard them referred to on reddit (especially his “famous resurrection ruleset) but I can’t find them anywhere.

Comment: So specifics: what well-known homebrew content actually entails, for specific rules (like the resurrection stuff); established: well-known, though not actual official content.

Answer (score 4):

#### Questions about homebrew content can be on-topic

Homebrew questions aren't categorically forbidden. Taking the Matt Mercer/Critical Role homebrew / 3rd party content you mentioned, there are a handful of decently received questions about aspects of it ([example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129053/37154)). There are also various other questions about homebrew, which can mostly be found at the [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) tag, or the related [house-rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) tag.

The specific types of questions you mention have some potential to be problematic for other reasons. When asking about "the specifics" of homebrew, there's a chance of treading too far into either "too broad" or "opinion-based" or sometimes "unclear". For example, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113735/37154) approximately of the form "My DM said this item exists what does it do?" can't be usefully answered because we aren't capable of reading a DM's mind like that. Critical Role content is less likely to fall into this category, especially if you can link and/or quote a source for its rules text. "Where can I find X?" is essentially covered in [a prior meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5944/37154), and the conclusion seems to be "probably off-topic" but you can ask in chat.

With regards to whether being "established" has an effect, it mostly means that you're likely to get better answers due to greater familiarity. It shouldn't have a substantial impact on whether your question is on-topic or not.

Comment: "Where can I find X" as a possible shopping question might be different if it's a well-known rule whose reference is difficult to find, though.

Comment: You said "Especially if you can link and/or quote a source for its rules text" - what if the question is where to find such a source? That's closer to what the question is worded towards.